# Jquery error : Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to using a tree structure on my JSP Page along with Jquery. Tree Structure requires to import few Jquery files. When I run the JSP page, I get the error code "Object doesn't support this property or method".

I tested the code by running the Tree Structure (Dyna Tree) code seperately and it works fine. Then I tried running the Jquery that I have written and it also works fine.  The above mentioned error only appears if I integrate both the code. I have writted my custom code and error where exactly it appears. 
NOTE : fm is name of the form on my JSP Page.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var url;
    function newUser(){
        $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Create New Access');
        $('#fm').form('clear');   // ERROR AT THIS LINE
        url = 'saveaccess.jsp'; 
    }
    function editUser(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit Access');
            $('#fm').form('load',row);
            alert("test"+row);
            //url = 'AddNeditApplication.jsp';
        }
    }
    function saveUser(){
        $('#fm').form('submit',{
            url: url,
            onSubmit: function(){
                return $(this).form('validate');
            },
            success: function(result){
                //var result =new Object();
                alert(result);

                if (result){
                    $('#dlg').dialog('close');      // close the dialog
                    $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                } else {
                    $.messager.show({
                        title: 'Error',
                        msg: result.msg
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function removeUser(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to remove this Access?',function(r){
                if (r){
                    $.post('AddNeditApplication.jsp',{id:row.id},function(result){
                        if (result.success){
                            $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                        } else {
                            $.messager.show({   // show error message
                                title: 'Error',
                                msg: result.msg
                            });
                        }
                    },'json');
                }
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Which line does this error refers to?

Comment: $('#fm').form('clear');   // ERROR AT THIS LINE

Comment: Can you post the segment of your relevant markup (`HTML`)?

Comment: Also if you're using `firefox` and `firebug` on the console after the page has loaded type: `$('#fm')` and see if what is returned is actually an object. If not then your form `fm` hasn't been rendered correctly

Answer (score 1):

`$('#fm').form('clear');` - Whenever JavaScript says "Object doesn't support this property or method", it's talking about the `.` operator.  Which means the object returned by calling `$('#fm')` doesn't support the method `form`.

I can't find any documentation in the jQuery API for a `form` method.  Perhaps you're trying to use [EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/form.php)?  Are you including the EasyUI scripts in your HTML in addition to jQuery (After jQuery, and before your code)?

Something like this:

```
<script src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

...?

Comment: Yes, I am including JEASYUI addition to Jquery                                  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Are you loading EasyUI _after_ jQuery?

Comment: Yes, first I am loading Jquery and followed by EasyUI.

Comment: That means `$('#fm')` isn't returning anything then doesn't it?

Comment: Lee, fm is returning value while I running the code without the tree structure code.

Comment: @user1710288: Can you recreate your issue using jsfiddle.net, or post a link to a (non) working example of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for Object doesn't support this property or method' exception:

1. Check and compare the browser version compatibility/support of the Jquery version. 
   i.e. IE8 does not support Jquery2x versions. In this scenario, use versions accordingly
2. The order of the files are wrong in your html/aspx file. Change order.. for example..

From...

```
 <script src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>      
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryFileTree.js"></script>
    <script src="js/default.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

To:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqueryFileTree.js"></script>
<script src="js/default.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
```

I was getting similar exception and now got resolved.